# Calling a function from a link in WordPress

Tags: plugins, functions

I am creating a WordPress plugin in which I have this function:

```
<?php 
    add_action('init','update_subscription');
     function update_subscription($category,$user_name){
      update_option($category,$user_name);
     }
```

and in same page I have some links.

```
<a href="">Subscribe</a>
```

I want to call the above function when the link is clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: AJAX is the cool thing to do!! There are a plenty of examples out there: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wordpress+ajax

Comment: Search this site for "AJAX API"